# How to validate one dropdown if the other dropdown is not selected and vice versa?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with 2 multi select dropdowns for list of country and list of sites....

I do form validation using jQuery Validate plugin....

**scenario to achieve**: if one dropdown is selected then i want the form to be submitted irrespective of second dropdown selected or not....

**current scenario of issue I face:** even if one dropdown is selected form is not submitting..form submits only if second dropdown is selected

I came across the `depends` attribute inside validate function..but it is not working either....

I am trying it for my 2 dropdowns with ids `list_country` and `list_site`

below is my code:

```
$('#feed_form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            list_country: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () { return $('#list_site').val() == null }
                }
            },
            list_site: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () { return $('#list_country').val() == null } 
                }
            },
            list_trend: {
                required: true  
            }
        },
        ignore: ":hidden:not(select)"
    });
```

form markup (source code as it is written in YII framework in php)

```
<form name="feed_form" id="feed_form" action="../minUser/DisplayUsers" method="post">       <div class="row">
            <div class="span3"><strong>Country:</strong></div>
            <div class="span3">
                   <select class="required multi_select" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%" onchange="js:$(&quot;#list_country_chzn&quot;).removeClass(&quot;error_container&quot;);" name="list_country[]" id="list_country">
<option value="666666">All</option>
<option value="5">xyz1</option>
<option value="5">xyz2</option>
<option value="5">xyz3</option>
<option value="5">xyz4</option>
<option value="5">xyz5</option>
<option value="5">xyz6</option>
</select>           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3"><strong>Site:</strong></div>
            <div class="span3">
                   <select class="required multi_select" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%" onchange="js:$(&quot;#list_site_chzn&quot;).removeClass(&quot;error_container&quot;);" name="list_site[]" id="list_site">
<option value="666666">All</option>
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
<option value="4">d</option>
</select>            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3"><strong>Trend:</strong></div>
            <div class="span3">
                   <select class="required" style="width:100%" name="list_trend" id="list_trend">
<option value="">--Select Trend--</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
</select>            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
            <div class="row buttons" align="left" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <input name="search_feed_form" class="btn btn-info" onclick="return checkVerifyForm();" type="submit" value="Search" />            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--end outermost box widget-->
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want the `require_from_group` method, which ensures only one `select` from the two is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> scenario to achieve: if one dropdown is selected then I want the form to be submitted irrespective of second dropdown selected or not.

You would want the `require_from_group` method, which is part of the Additional Methods file.  This rule, when properly assigned to both `select` elements, would simply ensure that at least one is selected.

<s>I would construct a working demo, but you have not shown us any of your HTML.</s>

1. You need to remove the `required` class as that will force the `required` rule and over-ride your `depends`. In the case of mine, it adds the `required` rule, which we do not want here.
2. Using the `rules` object, you must target the field's `name`, not the `id`.
3. Finally, instead of `depends`, you can use the `require_from_group` method to ensure only one `select` is required out of the two.

**DEMO: [jsfiddle.net/376otgfL/](http://jsfiddle.net/376otgfL/)**

```
$('#feed_form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        'list_country[]': {  // <- NAME, not id
            require_from_group: [1,".multi_select"]
        },
        'list_site[]': {     // <- NAME, not id
            require_from_group: [1,".multi_select"]
        },
        list_trend: {  // <- NAME, not id
            required: true
        }
    },
    ignore: ":hidden:not(select)"
});
```

Comment: will mark the answer once i have tried it...thanks for the suggestion....

Comment: solution works partially...now the `country and site` validation is taken care...but the `trend` dropdown doesnt get validated...
form submits if either `country` or `site` is selected and `trend` is not mandatory

Comment: @coolstoner, you need to check over your work.  As per the code you've given in your OP, `list_trend` is being validated just fine.  It's still working after applying my answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/376otgfL/

Comment: i will mark it as closed as the fiddle works right...will check my case...actually it is an chosen select dropdown...have just shown the html markup here....

Comment: @coolstoner, you have to made sure your `ignore` option is set correctly, and you might have to trigger validation with another handler.  Search SO for jQuery Validate and Chosen.

Comment: it is the line `ignore: ":hidden:not(select)"` which refuses to validate the `trend list` if site or country is validated...

using the chosen plugin of multi select hence the ignore line....

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working, unless I'm missing something.

```js
$(function() {
 
  
  
  $('#mySuperCoolForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            list_country: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () { return $('#list_site').val() == null }
                }
            },
            list_site: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () { return $('#list_country').val() == null } 
                }
            },
            list_trend: {
                required: true  
            }
        },
        ignore: ":hidden:not(select)"
    });
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="mySuperCoolForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select some stuff</legend>
    <select name="list_site" id="list_site" multiple="multiple">
                <option>thing 1</option>
                <option>thing 2</option>
                <option>thing 3</option>
                <option>thing 4</option>
                <option>thing 5</option>
            </select>
    <select name="list_country" id="list_country" multiple="multiple">
                <option>thing 1</option>
                <option>thing 2</option>
                <option>thing 3</option>
                <option>thing 4</option>
                <option>thing 5</option>
            </select>
    <input type="submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is working because it's not the same as the OP's.  Your version fixes two of his mistakes.

Comment: may i know those mistakes or what am i doing wrong?